# No space left on device OS error [Errno 28] when running python script. However, space and inodes are available

Tags: ubuntu, python

I am running a python script which generates jpegs images from svs files and I am getting the following error. I am running scripts from /home/ubuntu which is on /dev/xvda1

```
File "./scripts/00_preprocessing/0d_SortTiles_final.py", line 677, in <module>
    os.symlink(TilePath, NewImageDir)
OSError: [Errno 28] No space left on device: '/home/ubuntu/full_tiledslides/TCGA-44-2662-01B-01-BS1.C0473E69-AD92-4D16-B914-55F0A9C53320_files/20.0/102_50.jpeg' -> 'Alive/train_TCGA-44-2662-01B-01-BS1.C0473E69-AD92-4D16-B914-55F0A9C53320_102_50.jpeg'
```

I am using an aws ec2 p3.16xlarge and I have done this many times before with roughly the same size dataset. I deleted previous attempts to make room for this new attempt however, now I get this error.

```
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
udev            241G     0  241G   0% /dev
tmpfs            49G  8.9M   49G   1% /run
/dev/xvda1      2.0T  1.2T  792G  61% /
tmpfs           241G     0  241G   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs           5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
tmpfs           241G     0  241G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/loop1       90M   90M     0 100% /snap/core/8213
/dev/loop0       18M   18M     0 100% /snap/amazon-ssm-agent/1480
/dev/loop2       90M   90M     0 100% /snap/core/8268
/dev/loop3       18M   18M     0 100% /snap/amazon-ssm-agent/1455
tmpfs            49G     0   49G   0% /run/user/1000

Filesystem        Inodes    IUsed     IFree IUse% Mounted on
udev            62949231      347  62948884    1% /dev
tmpfs           62951205      468  62950737    1% /run
/dev/xvda1     262144000 31831794 230312206   13% /
tmpfs           62951205        1  62951204    1% /dev/shm
tmpfs           62951205        3  62951202    1% /run/lock
tmpfs           62951205       16  62951189    1% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/loop1         12842    12842         0  100% /snap/core/8213
/dev/loop0            15       15         0  100% /snap/amazon-ssm-agent/1480
/dev/loop2         12842    12842         0  100% /snap/core/8268
/dev/loop3            15       15         0  100% /snap/amazon-ssm-agent/1455
tmpfs           62951205        4  62951201    1% /run/user/1000
```

Comment: What is the filesystem on `/dev/xvda1`?

Comment: ext4. fsck doesn't work either

Comment: Did you try to create file in to the target directory. And do you have somewhere in to the target tree directory with more than 30k subdirectories?

Comment: Yeah I can create a file. And no I do not have any deep directory structures. I think it may have something to do with symbolic links. I cp files to the directory by cannot make symlinks.

Comment: What I see is second path is relative, right? If yes, try to set destination path to be full path.

Comment: Not sure why that would generate that error. I found a work around. The script actually works if I use os.system(cp file newlocation). But fails with os.symlink

Comment: Did you try with fill path?

Comment: Yeah it doesn't make a difference

Comment: Maybe you can try to ask the question here: https://stackoverflow.com/

Comment: I got my question removed from SO because they thought it was inappropriate